# str_i += e[0] + "\t" + e[1] + "\n"

Tags: python

I'm trying to print the stack but I'm getting this instead:

```
str_i += e[0] + "\t" + e[1] + "\n"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

How can I get the stack to print?

```
def __str__(self):
    str_i = 0
    for e in self.items:
        str_i += e[0] + "\t" + e[1] + "\n"
    return str_i       

s1 = Stack_2Queues()
s1.push(903, 12)
s1.push(767, 13)
s1.push(950, 14)
print(s1)
```

Comment: You define `str_i` when you do this: `str_i = 0` shouldnt it be `str_i = ""`?

Comment: ..and then `str_i += str(e[0]) + "\t" + str(e[1]) + "\n"`

Comment: Read and think about what the error message says. You are trying to concatenate essentially strings and integers. How would you fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
str_i = ''
for e in self.items:
    str_i += "{}\t{}\n".format(e[0],e[1])
```